# How to get a key of node in Angularfirelist<unknown> from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am getting these Categories form Firebase database.

Database Snapshot: [image]

here is `CategoryService` and `getCategories` is returning `AngularFireList<unknown>`.

```
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

   getCategories(){
     return this.db.list('/categories', category => category.orderByChild('name'));
   }
}
```

this is the `ProductComponant`.

```
export class ProductFormComponent {
  categories;
  constructor(
    categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {
    categoryService.getCategories().valueChanges().subscribe((categories) => {
      this.categories = categories;
    });
  }
```

in `categories` I am getting this.
 [image]

and this is the HTML markup

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select ngModel name="category" class="form-control" id="category">
            <option *ngFor="let c of categories" [value]="c.$key"> {{c.name}} </option>      
        </select>
    </div>
```

Here I want to get the key/id of every node in Categories and set it as Value in the category DropDown.

I have tried `c.key`, `c.$key`, `c.id` and `c | json`. but none works.

Comment: Can you present here what you are getting in categories?

Comment: @Sunny Parekh: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I get it. the problem is with `.valueChanges()` because it returns only data and not meta data. So i changed my code as.

CategoryService.ts:

```
export class CategoryService {
  aflCategories: AngularFireList<any>;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

   getCategories(){
     this.aflCategories = this.db.list('/categories', category => category.orderByChild('name'));
     return this.aflCategories
     .snapshotChanges()
     .pipe(map(changes => changes
     .map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))));
   }
}
```

ProductFormComponent.ts :

```
export class ProductFormComponent {

  categories$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private db: AngularFireDatabase
  ) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
  }
```

ProductFormComponent.html

```
<option *ngFor="let c of (categories$ | async)" [value]="c.key"> {{c.name}} </option>
```

and now i got the 'Key' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hey please change it as shown below:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <select name="category" class="form-control" id="category" [(ngModel)}="category">
            <option *ngFor="let c of categories" [ngValue]="c.name"> {{c.name}} </option>      
        </select>
    </div>
```

You should have a property called category in your controller file. Once you will make this change, on the selection you can see the selected value in the category variable.

Comment: c.name is returning the value of 'name' but i want the "Key" of the node. Like in the 'seasonings' node i want 'seasonings', not 'Seasonings and Spices'.